# Why ssh authentication fails after changing IP address?

Tags: authentication, ssh, ip

I recently changed the static IP address for local network of my Ubuntu 14.4
After doing that change I'm not able anymore to authenticate via ssh on the machine with root user. Tried from different clients on the network.
I Didn't make any change on machine's users

I got a permission denied

```
$ ssh root@192.168.1.13
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Should I go somewhere to update ssh users, according to the new IP?
I didn't find anything about this issue related to IP change.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible that you've restricted access to a specific network or interface.  What was the machine's IP previously?  Check the logs on the server to see what error messages are being spit out by `sshd`.

Comment: Update: I noticed I can't access via ssh only using root. Other user I can log in. I have set root password correctly before attempting. And restarted the ssh service.

Comment: You can also try `ssh -v root@192.168.1.13` to get more information from the client.  Add that output to your question.